# Yii jQuery BBQ error after delete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, jquery-bbq

I am using `Yii CGridView`. There is delete buttons in a column:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{update}{delete}',
    'buttons' => array(
        'delete' => array(
            'imageUrl' => false,
            'options' => array( 'class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-mini delete-button' ),
        )
    ),
)
```

After clicking delete button i see ajax request and directly after that I got js error

```
"URL is undefined" from jquery.ba-bbq.js @ 257 line (matches = url
 .match( is_fragment ? /^([^#]*)\#?(.*)$/ : /^([^#?]*)\??([^#]*)(#?.*)/ );).
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of that error?

P.s. entry is deleted, only js error.

Comment: Please post the line it errors on.

Comment: I hope you already did it, please clear application assets and try again.

Comment: @Mave : updated with that line

Comment: @RamkrishnaChaulagain : Yes, i have tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found solution [here](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/issues/236#issuecomment-16044349) :

Overwrite CGridView `registerClientScript` with this one:

```
public function registerClientScript(){

    //if ajaxUrl not set, default to the current action
    if(!isset($this->ajaxUrl))
        $this->ajaxUrl = Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("");

    //call parent function
    parent::registerClientScript();
}
```